Intercept keystroke sequence and return program stdout? (e.g. "ddd" -> `date -I`)
I know about text shortcuts in Mac OS System Preferences for the Keyboard that can replace input sequences with static text (e.g jd becomes John Doe). And these are useful.
But is there a way to achieve the same thing with dynamic output (maybe generated by a simple shell command)
I frequently need to insert today's date when writing notes in various apps. If I could convert ddd to sh -c "date -I" so that it inputs today's date, that would be great.
I know I can do this with individual apps (e.g. BBEdit, Email, Terminal) but is there a system wide way to achieve this? I'm hoping there's a tool that can intercept system events and invoke executables.

Do you just want to insert dates or do you want a text-replacement that is infinitely extensible?

Dates were just one example. I want to invoke shell commands.

There are third-party tools for this (I use Keyboard Maestro and Alfred, there are others). Without them, using Shortcuts might work (but would need key combos to trigger it, not short text).

Thanks, I've never heard of those. I'll have to see how they work.
